# How to avoid line crossing the markers when fillstyle = 'None'

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to replicate the plot below using Matplotlib:

[image: desired plot]

I tried with something like:

```py
plt.plot(x, y, color=‘red’, fillstyle=‘none’, marker=“*”, markersize=10)
```

The problem is that the line crosses the markers, and I would like to avoid this. Any idea on how to do that?

Comment: Please post an [mcve] that compiles. Your quotation marks are not valid python. plt isn't imported. x and y are not defined. What's the purpose of the backslash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `markerfacecolor="white"` instead of `fillstyle="none"`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [1, 2, 3]
y = [1, 2, 4]
plt.plot(x, y, color="red", marker="*", markersize=10, markerfacecolor="white")
```

[image]

Comment: Great, that's what I was looking for! I thought there was a simple solution to make it work. Many thanks!